# Instantiate a dynamic loaded class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, dynamic

I have an abstract class set up as follows:

```
export abstract class RuleValidator {
  public validate(condition: any, data: any) : boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have coded an extended class as follows:

```
import { RuleValidator } from "./interfaces/ruleValidator";

export class WeightValidator extends RuleValidator {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  validate(condition: any, data: any) : boolean {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(condition));
    return true;
   }
   public test() {
     console.log('Test successful');
   }
}
```

I am trying to load a class (the weight validator) only when validating a rule.  IE my ruleset has something like `{ "weight": { "gte": 2, "lt":9} }`

In my "engine" have the following code:

```
export class RulesEngineService() {
  validators = {};
  private validate(rule: Rule, data: any){
    for (const requirement of rule.requirements) {
      for (const condition in requirement){
        let validator = this.getRuleValidator(condition);
        let result = validator.validate( requirement[condition], data)
      }
    }

  }

  private  getRuleValidator(validatorName: string): RuleValidator {
    validatorName = validatorName ? validatorName.toLocaleLowerCase() : validatorName;

    // populate only if validator doesn't exist
    if (typeof this.validators[ validatorName ] === 'undefined') {
      const Validator = require( '../ruleValidator/' + validatorName);
      const validator = new Validator();
      this.validators[validatorName] = validator;
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return this.validators[validatorName]
    }
  }
}
```

In the past, in JavaScript Node, I could simply do a require on the file with the class in it and instanciate it with a `var Validator = require('/path/to/lib' + filename); validator = new Validator()` as you see in the call above.

My problem is, i get an error that `Validator is not a function` when it tries to run the `validator = new Validator();` line of code.  I see the object structure in VSCode debugger looks like

```
   {
     WeightValidator: class WeightValidator.....
     __esModule:true
   }
```

What I am needing is to store a reference to the instance of the class I just "required" and store it in the object I set up as well as return that reference to the calling method.  That way, I can call the validate function in that class.  I plan to create many different validators and they will have custom logic in them to do the validation work.

I've tried a few different ideas like wrapping the load in a promise with something like this:

```
      const validator  = (async () => {
        let f = '../ruleValidator/' + validatorName;
        const v = await import(f);
        return v; 
      })().then(v => {
        const s = v.validate(condition, data)
        return s;
      });
```

I get told the validate method doesn't exist.  Also, to be honest, I don't need it run async yet.  I just would like to duplicate the functionality from JavaScript require in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the class export as `default` export, which is explained in the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

```
// 'weightValidator.ts'
import { RuleValidator } from "./interfaces/ruleValidator";


// use the `default` export
export default class WeightValidator extends RuleValidator {
  
  //...

}
```

With that you should be able to use

```
// 'ruleEngineService.ts'
const Validator = require( '../ruleValidator/' + validatorName);
const validator = new Validator();
```

---

Another approach could be:

```
// 'weightValidator.ts'
import { RuleValidator } from "./interfaces/ruleValidator";

export class WeightValidator extends RuleValidator {
  
  //...

}

// use a separate export which has the same name for all validators.
export const sameExportNameForAllValidators = WeightValidator;
```

And then:

```
// 'ruleEngineService.ts'
const Validator = require( '../ruleValidator/' + validatorName).sameExportNameForAllValidators;
const validator = new Validator();
```

Comment: Using the first option still gives me the "Validator is not a constructor" error.

Trying the second approach gave me the following error when i tried to use the const getValidator for both classes.

  `src/domain/ruleValidator/index.ts:2:1 - error TS2308: Module './postalCode' has already exported a member named 'getValidator'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.

2 export * from './weight';`

Comment: My mistake.  Trying the second approach did work .  I originally thought it didn't cause I did come up with a solution finally, but it required me to export each class in an index.ts file and then translate the short name (like postalCode) to the class name PostalCodeValidator.